# Where should the binary files generated by vscode run the "go run ./{filename}.go" command be placed?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Where should the binary files generated by vscode run the "go run ./{filename}.go" command be placed?  The executable file generated after running the command go run ./server.go is in C:\Users\Panny\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1572652710\b001\exe\server.go, which is too difficult to find. How to specify the output path

Run go build -o path/mypath to specify the path, but how to configure it?

Comment: we need to debug binary in vscode, is that your case or you just want to build the application?

Comment: Don’t use go run with filename arguments. Go run doesn’t really create a binary you are supposed to know about.

Comment: I know that use go run does not actually create a binary file, but sometimes I need to use the http module, and then use go run to generate server.exe.
main.go is used as client, using go run does not generate exe

Comment: Then do a simple `go build`.

Comment: thank u ,I got it